# How to load the component as a option to the dynamically loaded component through service in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have base component and I am trying to load the

1. header component,
2. body component and
3. footer component

to make it has popup component dynamically.

I am calling the service like below:-

```
modelservice.open(headerComponent,bodyComponent,FooterComponent)
```

i am not able to comeup with the model on this service call.

Comment: Add more details on your question  and share the code as well.

Comment: basically i want to create model component. this model should contain 1)default-header component 2) default-bodycomponent 3) default-footer component . but i need to create model using these three components through service

Comment: Are you referring to any standard modal from Bootstrap or any other framework ?

Comment: yes, it something like ng-bootstrap but i have separate components for header,content and footer. dynamically i need to attach these components to make it model component